# Codeigniter: function return statement not returning

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, ubuntu

I am trying to return a db value using the following function in case of failure the function is supposed to return an error object. I have separated the code block with If/else statement. The if condition satisfies and the if block is executed. But for some reason the return statement in the if block do not execute and the code execution continues to next statement. I tried the two options on both cases the results are same.

First Code

```
public function is_defined_headtype($head_id)
{
    if ($is_defined = $this->ci->account_head_model->is_defined_headtype($head_id))
    {
        echo "Im here<br>";
        return $this->_success($is_defined, ACC_SUCCESS);
    }

    echo "Im here also";
    // General Error Occurred
    return $this->_general_error();
}
```

Second Code

```
public function is_defined_headtype($head_id)
{
    if ($is_defined = $this->ci->account_head_model->is_defined_headtype($head_id))
    {
        echo "Im here<br>";
        return $this->_success($is_defined, ACC_SUCCESS);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Im here also";
        // General Error Occurred
        return $this->_general_error();
    }
}
```

In both cases I am getting the following output.

```
Im here
Im here also{"err":1,"code":1,"msg":"Error"}
```

Calling function definition

```
public function add_eam($user_id, $eamname, $entityid, $headid, $eamdescription, $eamisfraction, $eampercentage, $eamamount, $affectedheadid)
{
    if (/* $eam_id = $this->ci->account_eam_model->insert_eam($user_id, $eamname, $entityid, $headid) */ true)
    {
        $is_defined = $this->is_defined_headtype(/* $headid */1);
        echo json_encode($is_defined);
        if($is_defined == 1)
        {
            echo "Im here";
            exit();
            if ($entity_id = $this->ci->account_eam_definition_model->insert_eam_definition(/* $user_id */ 1, $eam_id, $eamdescription, $eamisfraction, $eampercentage, $eamamount, $affectedheadid))
            {
                return $this->_success($eam_id, ACC_ENTITY_ADDED);
            }
            else 
            {
                return $this->_general_error();
            }
        }
        echo "Im not here";
        exit();
        return $this->_success($eam_id, ACC_ENTITY_ADDED);
    }

    // General Error Occurred
    return $this->_general_error();

}
```

Comment: Output of second code ? it only outputs if or else only

Comment: as @safinchacko said, what you are saying doesnt make sense. In your _"Second Code"_ you have an `if/else` each with a `return` this means that either one code block or the other will show. Are you sure you are getting both `"Im here"` and `"Im here also"` outputs on the second code?

Comment: {"err":1,"code":1,"msg":"Error"} this is from the calling function. which says that instead of the success object it returns the error object.

Comment: @CodeGodie I totally agree that it does not make sense hence I posted and need to know why this is happening and how do I fix it.

Comment: gotcha, just had to make sure you posted correctly.  Hmmm... Where is this method? `is_defined_headtype()` is it a controller or model method?

Comment: call sequence is as follows

Controller
action()->_library_function_A()
_library_function_A()->model_object->model_function_b()
model has both the functions.
is_defined_headtype() is a local function.

Comment: The only way this could be happening is if `is_defined_headtype()` is being called twice. The first time it runs, it outputs the `if` return and the second time it runs, it outputs the `else`. How are you calling these methods?

Comment: It is called only once.

Comment: edit your original question and show where you are calling this method. Include the controller class, model class, and library class so that we can see the bigger picture.

Comment: added the calling function definition. both the function are on the same file so both are local.

Comment: how are you calling `add_eam()`?

Comment: from controller. It is being called only once. I have checked the call sequence and its being called only once.

Comment: Incorrect [comparision](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is used in `if` [structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php). There should be `==` or `===` to check equality.

Answer (score 0):

hi i think the error is here
you are doing an if statement with only one '=' this is to set a value but you want to comapre so that should be:

'==' to compare that two values are the same 
 '!=' to see if the two values are different

```
public function is_defined_headtype($head_id)
{
    if ($is_defined = $this->ci->account_head_model->is_defined_headtype($head_id))
    {
        echo "Im here<br>";
        return $this->_success($is_defined, ACC_SUCCESS);
    }

    echo "Im here also";
    // General Error Occurred
    return $this->_general_error();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In *If* statement try Type Juggling `(int)` or use `===` for strong compare with both side data.

Comment: What is type 'hinting', never heard of that before.

Comment: There are multiple if conditions. Can you give a more clear answer and maybe a small piece of example code to show how this answers the question?